# How to Avoid Explicit Casting using Generics

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, datagridview, casting

I have a routine which converts all the data in a `DataGridView` to a corresponding `DataTable`. I want to extend this method to incorporate the ability to convert just the selected range of the `DataGridView`. I can clearly do this using basic logic `if (bIsSelection) /*Do stuff*/ else /*Do other stuff*/` but I would like to use generics here. The problem is that the full `DataGridView` range is a `DataGridViewColumnCollection` and the selected range will be a `DataGridViewSelectedColumnCollection` and C# does not seem to like any conversion between the two, or allow implicit typing in the case of generics.

The first part of my code was

```
public static DataTable BuildDataSetFromDgv(DataGridView _dataGridView, 
    string strTabName)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.TableName = strTabName;
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in _dataGridView.Columns)
        dt.Columns.Add(col.DataPropertyName, col.ValueType);
```

and I have attempted

```
public static DataTable BuildDataSetFromDgv<T>(DataGridView _dataGridView, 
    string strTabName, ICollection<T> _columnColl, ICollection<T> _rowColl)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.TableName = strTabName;
    //foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in _dataGridView.Columns)
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in _columnColl)
        dt.Columns.Add(col.DataPropertyName, col.ValueType);
```

which does not work due to the implicit conversion, and changing `_columnColl` to `_columnColl as DataGridView[Selected]ColumnCollection` defeats the objective.

How do I make this work with generics in this case?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Note, both of these collections implement `ICollection`.

Comment: Thanks. I typed this on the fly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you need a generic one - both are collection of `DataGridViewColumn`. For example, why below shouldn't work for you

```
public static DataTable BuildDataSetFromDgv(DataGridView _dataGridView, 
    string strTabName, IEnumerable columns)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.TableName = strTabName;

    var dvgColumns = columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>();
    foreach (var col in dvgColumns)
        dt.Columns.Add(col.DataPropertyName, col.ValueType);
```

Comment: +1 Great answer. I was not familiar with this type of casting.